# EF 7 : INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an exception when I call SaveChangesAsync.
My architecture is really simple, i have a Category class, wich contains

```
public class Category {
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public Guid? ParentId {get; set;}
  public Category Parent {get; set;}
 [...]
}
```

When I want to insert a new category in database (connected to my ASP MVC application), I set the GUID before doing the insert. 
The error occured when my database is empty and I want to insert parent category (so with a null Guid IdParent and null Parent). This is NOT happening if I set a parent value. I can add a record manually by setting parent to Null by Visual studio.

I have the following error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "FK_Category_Category_ParentId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "HT_Root", table "dbo.Category", column 'ID'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

I searched on stack overflow for a simple answer, and not found it. 
I try with Fluent API :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOne(s => s.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentId);
```

But nothing changed. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried `HasOptional` instead of `HasOne`?

Comment: @SergeyKolodiy I don't have any HasOptional in EF 7 fluent API ... ?

Comment: Can you insert the row manually in the database, like with SSMS?  This sounds like your database table is not set up properly.

Comment: I can add it by Visual Studio yes

Comment: Unfortunaly, yes, in my database schema, ParentId is a FK, uniqueidentifier, Null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to have changed in EF 7 [See this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1467)

Try

```
public class Category 
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public Guid? ParentId {get; set;}
    public Category Parent {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Categories> Children {get; set;}
}
```

And

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x => x.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
    .Required(false);
```

You should also always check that (if specified) the ParentId exists in the database. Watch out for adding `Guid.Empty` (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) instead of `null` as this can cause issues.

Comment: Are you inserting a record with or without a parent id?

Comment: It initialy works with a parent ID, but didn't and still don't work without parent ID

Comment: So you are posting some values via http and it is not working, but if you add the values in an initializer it does work?

Comment: In both cases I post some values via http

Comment: And you are absolutely certain that the parent id exists?

Comment: My issue is that parentID doesn't exists because I want to add with null value (add a category without Parent). If I add with one, it works perfectly...

Comment: Have you double checked that in the database that ParentId is of type `(FK, uniqueidentifier, null)`

Comment: Sometimes you can post Guid.Empty (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) instead of null - have you double checked that?

Comment: It is that o__o .... I was sure to check it but yeah, in my InsertOrUpdate method, ParentID is Guid.Empty, not null .... How can I make it to null by default ? I set null value in Category ctor ...

Comment: You can always set it just before the update `if (ParentId == Guid.Empty) ParentId = null;`

Comment: That's what I do, but it doesn't seems to be the perfect way ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101607/discussion-between-ste-fu-and-cdie).

Comment: I think this was not solved. Just set ParentId default value as null in entity definition.Otherwise ef always generate a id.